# Chess GUI showing variations with arrows except SCID?

Tags: software

Is there anything else except Scid / Scid vs PC that shows variations with arrows and also allows you to chose any variation simply by dragging the piece on the board?

Comment: I'm sure Chessbase does that.

Comment: @SmallChess Have you ever seen/done it yourself or you just think CB should do that? Because those are two completely different things.

Comment: I've seen people use ChessBase software and using arrows and square highlighting many times. And I'm not sure what you mean, but sure you can make any move and e.g. the opening book will jump to that position.

Comment: @TMM I wasn't talking about graphical annotations. "but sure you can make any move and e.g. the opening book will jump to that position" And what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Taking such a hostile approach towards people trying to help you is a bad idea. Your question is unclear, which is not our fault.

Comment: @TMM How is that hostile??

Comment: Chessbase does all of these functions.  Chesspad is free and has these functions.

Comment: @Fred Knight Can you please elaborate on how to do that in ChessBase.or Chesspad? Thank you.

Comment: @TMM I didn't really mean to be hostile. But I'm sorry if that's how it appeared to you. Thank you for your trying to help.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that what you want is that what you want applies to a game from a database/pgn file which has variations in it. If you go to a certain position in that game, the program should display arrows of all variations (=first move of all *saved* variations)?  I'd imagine this could be rather messy if you have lots of variations/arrows. Why are you not satisfied with using scid, if it does what you want?

Comment: @user1583209 I don't like Scid's gui. I use Scid vs PC a lot (even though it's not pretty either) but the thing is it's not very stable on my computer. Yes, if you go to a positions with variations the programs shows them all with arrows. I like this approach for repertoire studying. Frankly, I don't know what could be messy about it. You see the board, the position and  arrows show all the sensible moves your imaginary opponent could play.

Comment: @user1583209 Normally you don't need "lots of variations/arrows" (if we're not talking about the very beginning of the game) in your repertoire. Usually it's about 3, 4 or 5 (at best) possible continuations.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
You can add a new variation by entering any legal move.  If the variation is not already listed, both will add it for you, Chessbase does ask beforehand.

The arrows are drawn by holding down the "alt" key and dragging the mouse between squares.  The colored squares are made by holding down the "alt" key and clicking a square.  The default color is green, holding down the "ctrl" key changes it to yellow, and the "shift" key for red. All require the "alt" key to be held down.  To remove the markings, repeat the procedure.

Winboard has a feature that automatically draws an arrow indicating the last move made.

All markings remain.  If you return to any move, any markings you made are still present.

Although you can chose a variation by moving the piece, these programs allow you to use the cursor keys to obtain the same thing.

Comment: your screenshot shows that you didn't understand my question. Please read it carefully once more. I'm not asking about software where I can draw arrows manually. The program I am looking for should indicate variations with arrows automatically. I mentioned Scid and the fork Scid vs PC for a reason.

Comment: I reread your question, and it's not clear that you wanted the arrows to indicate the variations.  After testing Scid*, I now understand what you're looking for.  You could try and alter the GUI.  About it not being stable is the problem.  Although the source code is provided, finding what makes it unstable without a lot of testing would be very difficult.  Send a feedback to the authors, and they might update the program.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Arena with Komodo but it doesn't have such arrows. Although you can try lichess.org's online analyser. It shows arrows per move and uses stockfish so it will be a pretty good choice if you aren't looking for a offline one.

ctrl+ move a piece to a legal square makes an arrow

Comment: I do use lichess' analysis boards quite often and mainly because of opening explorer but never seen it showing any variation arrows that I'm asking about here.

Comment: @AhuLee can you post a screenshot of what you are actually looking for? It will help us understand better.

Comment: there is no point in it. Everything has already been discussed here in comments and it's all clear already what I am/was looking for.